# How to send custom matrics and custom dimension using Google Analytics for Firebase in android

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics

How can we send custom dimension and custom matrics using `Google Analytics for Firebase`? I have read [Google Analytics for Firebase](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7388022?hl=en&ref_topic=2587085) and also implemented it with help of this link [implement Google Analytics for Firebase](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2587086?hl=en). It is working and I can see it on real time tracking, But I want to know that how can we send analytics parameter that is use in GA like Custom matrics and Custom Dimension? I did not find any link or idea about it.

Comment: How did you finally deal with this?

Comment: I found the answer in [this post](https://growthbug.com/i-took-firebase-analytics-for-a-ride-heres-the-conclusion-8a148a2e6229). Custom dimensions are now called user properties

Comment: man, it helped me a lot. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

**My Answer:**

Steps 1: Access the official set-up docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start/

Step 2: Access the firebase debugview to test your event set-up in real-time: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview or access intra-day tables in BigQuery.

Step 3: Your data will start showing up within 24 hours (if enough users triggers it).